# NLog application level variables

Tags: c#, .net, nlog

I'm tasked with a WPF app & have chosen NLog for our logging.

I note answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44736889/how-to-setup-a-per-request-global-variable-for-nlog) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12424301/how-do-i-log-a-custom-field-in-nlog-to-database) I would like to do something similar but with .net Desktop & with more control.

I would like to set a guid once at app start and each log entry (at any level) have this guid included automatically, so I can search on that guid. Creating a new guid when the user logs in.

Going further it would actually be good knowledge to know if I can programmatically add **any** variables that get included with every Log I make, so I dont have to add them to each and every Log.AnyLevel, an example output:

```
DateTime | LoginID | SessionGuid | MyMessage
```

to get this output I like to only do:

```
logger.Trace("MyMessage")
```

LoginID & SessionGuid being set either when App starts or I instantiate a ViewModel or the User Logs in.

I note at present I can do this *per log* with

```
LogEventInfo
```

How can I add a variable once (from code) and have it always included?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can setup a NLog GDC variable:

```
GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set("AppGuid",Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
```

And then reference that in your layouts:

```
${gdc:item=AppGuid}
```

See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Gdc-layout-renderer

Comment: Oh right, I have looked at GDC but was under the impression it was obsolete (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/17767739/425357)

Comment: GDC is usually for global data that stays pretty much the same for the lifetime of the application. LogEvent-properties should be used for context-specific or logevent-specific variables.

Comment: Thank you, appreciate your time.

Comment: Happy to help. Have modified the stackoverflow answer you referred to with more correct details.